# Using Osmosis library to query data from a PBF file

Tags: openstreetmap, query, database, osmosis

I know that it's possible to read (`crosby.binary.osmosis.OsmosisReader`) and write (`crosby.binary.osmosis.OsmosisSerializer`) a PBF file using the [Osmosis library](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osmosis/).

My question is if it's possible using the library (or any semi-official java library) to access the PBF data by querying entities (nodes/ways/relations) by its ID and editing them?

If not, does the Osmosis library have an easy way to port PBF data to a database other than just using `OsmosisReader` to read through all the entities?